# Description not based on database

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I can retrieve data from the database and it works now, but only on the first line (both *description* and *code* are correct and based on the database).

On the second line, the *description* is not based on the database, however it display the *description* for the first line, even though the code for first and second line are different. How do I fix that?

Here is some code:

```
private void UpdateDatas()
{
  int codeValue = 0;

  OleDbDataReader dReader;
  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
  conn.Open();
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
    "SELECT [Description], [Price] FROM [Data] WHERE [Code]=@Code", conn);

  cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

  if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].Text, out codeValue))
  {
    cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = codeValue;
  }
  else if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][1].Text, out codeValue))
  {
    cmd.Parameters["Code"].Value = codeValue;
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
  }

  dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  while (dReader.Read())
  {
    if (textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].TextLength != 0)
    {
      this.textBoxDescContainer[0][0].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
      this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][0].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
    }

    if (textBoxCodeContainer[0][1].TextLength != 0)
    {
      this.textBoxDescContainer[0][1].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
      this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][1].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
    }
  }

  dReader.Close();
  conn.Close();
 }
```

Here is the image:
[image: code in the first line is "0002" and the description for it is "B", this is correct (based on database), but code in the second line is "0005", and the description for it supposed to be "E", but this is show "B", it is like copy the description in the first line, even though code is different]

Here is the image of the database:
[image]

Comment: Out of interest, why aren't you using a `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you processes first record twice in your loop, for both text boxes. Try this as a quick fix:

```
int index = 0;
while (dReader.Read())
{
  if (textBoxCodeContainer[0][index].TextLength != 0)
  {
    this.textBoxDescContainer[0][index].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
    this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[0][index].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
  }

  index += 1;
}
```

The second problem, is that you add two values for one parameter (Code) in your query, so the result of the select will contain only one row. You should you the "IN" SQL keyword. The second quick fix would concern your query:

```
var query = "SELECT [Description], [Price] FROM [Data] WHERE [Code] IN (";

 if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][0].Text, out codeValue))
 {
 query = query + codeValue.ToString();
 }
 if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0][1].Text, out codeValue))
 {
 query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
 }

 query = query + ")";

 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
 dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

How to parametrize the query with the "IN" clause is another problem - this is just a quick fix to make this work.